# sensor output level shifter

Tags: input-offset-voltage

I am trying to read a map sensor with an ads1232 ADC.
The Map sensor requires 0v(ground) and 5v+ and outputs 2.5v fluctuating +-2.5v depending on the pressure. The ads1232 can read +-2.5v but without the 2.5v DC offset. Has anyone got any simple ideas or can lead me in the right direction on how to shift the 2.5v back to ground.

Thanks

Comment: Is there a 2.5V stable Vref  handy? got an Op Amp?

Comment: See pin 16 of Figure 44. on how to measure with 2.5V ref signals

Comment: yes it does have positive vref and negative vref on the ads1232.

Comment: perfect, thanks for taking the time to read the datasheet, I will source a reference diode

Answer (score 0):

You can build a subtractor: https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/opamp/opamp_5.html

But why not purchase an ADC capable of 0-5V input range?

Comment: I needed 24bit resolution

Comment: @Adrian yes then build a subtractor :) assuming you have dual ended supply available for the op amp rails